# code tuning for nested loops for better performance

Tags: java, nested-loops

What a good way you think is useful to code tune this code for better efficiency?

```
int[][] table = new int[1000][10];
for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++)
        table[i][j] = i * j;
```

Comment: `int[][] table = new int[1000][10];` -- This is not C++.  Also, why are you tagging both Java and C++, when they are not the same language?

Comment: Which is it: Java or C++?

Comment: Sorry, I removed the c++ tag

Answer (score 2):

These will help (a little):

- Use constants where you can
- Don't assign 0 to elements that are already 0
- Take advantage of the order you walk the array to avoid explicit multiplication

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is do some math and try to deduce the time complexity from O(n^2).

The solution below removes the most costly operation, the multiply. I didn't test to make sure, but something similar should work.

```
int[][] table = new int[1000][10];
for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
    int t = i;
    for(int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++)
        t += j;
        table[i][j] = t;
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like that, I prefer to do this.

```java
int TLEN = 1000;
int STLEN = 10;
int[][] table = new int[TLEN][];
for(int i = 0; i < TLEN; i++) {
    int [] subtable = new int[STLEN];
    for(int j = 0; j < STLEN; j++) {
        subtable[j] = i * j;
    }
    table[i] = subtable;
}
```

But I can't say if it is more or less efficient.